# Importing custom DB table entries as posts with Categories

Tags: terms, wp-insert-post

I'm using the following code to import all entries within a custom DB table as posts. The function fires from an init hook.

All taxonomies are created, and all entries from the DB are imported, however I am finding that half of the entries within the DB are not having their terms set. The other half are and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have full debugging mode on, and have also used is_wp_error but nothing is being output to suggest any issues.

```
<?php

/**
 * Set the playlist entry category.
 *
 * @since   1.3
 * @param   int     $event_id   The event ID.
 * @param   int     $term_id    The category term ID.
 * @return  bool    True on success, otherwise false.
 */
function mdjm_set_playlist_entry_category( $event_id, $term_id )    {
    $set_entry_type = wp_set_post_terms( $event_id, $term_id, 'playlist-category' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $set_entry_type ) )   {
        return false;
    }
    else    { 
        return true;
    }
} // mdjm_set_playlist_entry_category

/**
 * Create terms for each of the playlist categories.
 *
 * @since   1.3
 * @param
 * @return  void
 */
function mdjm_create_playlist_terms()   {
    global $wpdb;

    $cats = mdjm_get_option( 'playlist_cats' );

    $terms = explode( "\r\n", $cats );

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) )    {
        foreach( $terms as $term )  {
            $new_term = wp_insert_term( $term, 'playlist-category' );

            if( is_wp_error( $new_term ) )  {
                error_log( $new_term->get_error_message() );
            }
        }
    }

    wp_insert_term( __( 'Guest', 'mobile-dj-manager' ), 'playlist-category' );
} // mdjm_create_playlist_terms

/**
 * Create terms for each of the playlist categories.
 *
 * @since   1.3
 * @param
 * @return  void
 */
function mdjm_import_playlist_entries() {
    global $wpdb;

    if( get_option( 'mdjm_playlist_import' ) )  {
        return;
    }

    // Create the terms
    mdjm_create_playlist_terms();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM 
             " . $wpdb->prefix . "mdjm_playlists";

    $entries = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    if( $entries )  {
        add_option( 'mdjm_playlist_import', false );
        foreach( $entries as $entry )   {
            $meta = array(
                'song'          => isset( $entry->song )             ? $entry->song              : '',
                'artist'        => isset( $entry->artist )           ? $entry->artist            : '',
                'added_by'      => isset( $entry->added_by )         ? $entry->added_by          : get_current_user_id(),
                'djnotes'       => isset( $entry->info )             ? $entry->info           : '',
                'added_date'    => isset( $entry->date_added )       ? $entry->date_added       : '',
                'to_mdjm'       => isset( $entry->date_to_mdjm )     ? date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $entry->date_to_mdjm ) )   : '',
                'uploaded'      => isset( $entry->upload_procedure ) ? $entry->upload_procedure  : '',
            );

            $term        = isset( $entry->play_when )   ? $entry->play_when : 'General';
            $event_id   = isset( $entry->event_id )    ? $entry->event_id  : '';

            if( empty( $term ) || $term == 'Guest Added' )  {
                $term = 'Guest';
            }

            $title = sprintf( __( 'Event ID: %s %s %s', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                mdjm_get_option( 'event_prefix', '' ) . $event_id,
                $meta['song'],
                $meta['artist'] );

            $category = get_term_by( 'name', $term, 'playlist-category' );

            $entry_id = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                    'post_type'     => 'mdjm-playlist',
                    'post_title'    => $title,
                    'post_author'   => 1,
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'post_parent'   => $event_id,
                    'post_date'     => isset( $entry->date_added )? date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $entry->date_added ) ) : date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
                    'post_category' => !empty( $category ) ? array( $category->term_id ) : ''
                )
            );

            if( ! empty( $category ) )  {
                mdjm_set_playlist_entry_category( $entry_id, $category->term_id );
            }

            foreach( $meta as $key => $value ) {
                update_post_meta( $entry_id, '_mdjm_playlist_entry_' . $key, $value );
            }
        }
        update_option( 'mdjm_playlist_import', true );
    }
} // mdjm_import_playlist_entries
add_action( 'init', 'mdjm_import_playlist_entries', 15 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Just needed to add `trim` to the term names retrieved from the custom DB table!! D'oh!